# The behaviour of receiving request with expired api_key in Moqui

Tags: moqui

What is the system behavior  of receiving a request to A restful API with a expired api_key in Moqui? Does the system send back the SC_UNAUTHORIZED error or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is status with 500 internal server error.

Comment: As a update, the  by 2017 Feb, 14, Moqui returns a 410 error.